# Custom color not available

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add a custom Color to my project, but for some reason it is not appearing in `R.color`. I have added a `colors.xml` file as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="bronze">#ffc125</color>
</resources>
```

and now when I try to use the new colour as follows

```
paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bronze));
```

I get a compile error as bronze does not appear in the list. I've tried moving the definition to styles.xml but it still doesn't appear. I've also tried cleaning the project to force R to rebuild but it didn't make any difference either. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Try doing a Project clean - sometimes changes to xml files are not picked up.

Comment: check the imports... whether you are importing android.R class or R class from your package

Comment: Note that `getColor();` returns an `int`, not a `Color`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the import of android.R and then build again.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it I was using Android R and not my project's. Thanks to Gopal Rao also for suggesting this in the comments

Answer (score 0):

`getColor()` returns int so set to the view you need to use the color

resource xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="bronze">#8C7853</color>
    </resources>
```

setColor to the view,here i used in textview

```
  textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.errorColor));
```

Comment: Thanks, you're correct that I was trying to use it incorrectly and I have edited my question. Unfortunately I still cannot access the new colour